# Emulating Django models ? (Simple implementation - Missing something)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to emulate django models :

> In Django :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
if User.objects.get(pk=1) == User.objects.get(username='root')
    print 'True'
else:
    print 'False'
# True is printed
```

> My implementation :

```
 class MyUser:
      def __init__(self, id):
          self.id = id

 class User:
     class objects:
         @staticmethod
         def get(**kwargs):
             return MyUser(1)

if User.objects.get(pk=1) == User.objects.get(username='root')
    print 'True'
else:
    print 'False'
# False is printed
```

**How to correct my implementation to get 'True' ?**

How can I achieve the same effect ?
What change shall I do ?

Comment: What's the problem man ? can I add something more to be more clear ?

Comment: Why would you think that it would be true?

Comment: Basically, I want to know the how can I achieve the same effect ?

Comment: Let me edit the question to be precise !

Comment: I feel this is really an interesting aspect of django, please if you feel more info please comment, but don't down-vote and make the question loose importance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is simply that you haven't defined `__eq__` on your class, so Python has no idea how to compare them. Something like this would work:

```
class MyUser(object):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.id == other.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because Django's `Model`s implement a `__eq__` method:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return isinstance(other, self.__class__) and self._get_pk_val() == other._get_pk_val()
```

You could implement a similar method on your `MyUser` class to achive a similar effect.

See also: [the documentation on `__eq__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__).